# Edit file properties in PDF with GemBox.Document

Tags: c#, pdf, gembox-document

How can we modify all properties in PDF file?
I've seen the [document properties example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/word-properties/211) and ended up with this:

```
DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load("Input.docx");

document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.Application] = "My Application";
document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.Title] = "My Title";
document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.Author] = "My Author";
// Etc ...

document.Save("Output.pdf");
```

But some properties are missing, for instance there is no `Producer` and `Creator` enums in [BuiltInDocumentProperty](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/help/html/T_GemBox_Document_BuiltInDocumentProperty.htm). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BuiltInDocumentProperty` enums are based on Word documents, but nevertheless try the following example:

```
// The "BuiltInDocumentProperty.Application" is the PDF's "Creator" property.
// If you're experiencing an issue with it, try downloading the latest bug fix version:
// https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/downloads/BugFixes.htm
document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.Application] = "My Application";

// The PDF's "Producer" property is missing, but you can use the following:
document.DocumentProperties.Custom.Add("Producer", "My Producer");

document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.Title] = "My Title";
document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.Author] = "My Author";
document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.Subject] = "My Subject";
document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.Keywords] = "My Keywords";
document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.DateContentCreated] =
    new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).ToString("s") + "Z";
document.DocumentProperties.BuiltIn[BuiltInDocumentProperty.DateLastSaved] =
    new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).ToString("s") + "Z";
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mario, the build-in "Application" and custom "Producer" properties worked! Also thank you for the date related properties, it'll come in handy.